# how I Backing Up SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am new to SQL Server Admin and am hoping to get some help? I have a database that only contains views of data from another database. It has no tables at all.
Is there a way to backup the data in the views?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you back up "another database."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have taken steps to backup the other database that contains the real data, you could also backup the views from your **views only database**, by scripting them out using SQL Server Management Studio

From SQL Server Management Studio
Via Object Explorer

1. Expand the database you wish to backup views for
2. Right click on the database and select Tasks -> Generate Scripts
3. Choose "Select specific database objects"
4. Check views or just the views you want to backup

[image]

5. Select Next
6. Choose Save to new query window

[image]

7. Choose next and then next again
8. Click on finish and the view or views you selected will be scripted to a new window